# Adding a list of variable values to a list in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, append, common-lisp

This is my first post so I apologize if I'm too vague or haven't done this correctly!

So I have an empty list L1 and two variables x and y which can be anything.

Say for example x = 10 and y = 20.

I would like the list L1 to start with x, and then I have a WHEN loop that add's y to the list every time it loops but I can't seem to get the list in the format I would like.

I currently have:

```
(let ((L1 x)))                  ; Adds x to the list

(loop

  (when (> n 10) (return))      ; While n < 10, add's y to the list.

  (setq L1 (list L1 y))

  (incf n)))
```

Which returns:

```
(10 20)
((10 20) 20)
(((10 20) 20) 20)
((((10 20) 20) 20) 20)
(((((10 20) 20) 20) 20) 20) ...
```

However I would like it to return:

```
( (10) (20) )
( (10) (20) (20) )
( (10) (20) (20) (20) )
( (10) (20) (20) (20) (20) )
( (10) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) ) ...
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((x 10) (y 20) (n 10))
    (cons (list x)
          (loop 
            for i from 1 to n
            collect (list y)))))
```

then

```
(test)
=> ((10) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20) (20))
```

or

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((x 10) (y 20) (n 10))
    (cons (list x) (make-list n :initial-element (list y)))))
```

Comment: Okay great, thanks! How do I set the list in your first example to L1?

Comment: `(setq L1 (test))` or `(setq L1 (cons (list x) ...)`.